# PreparedStatment Error when Adding Array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, spring

I am using the SPRING famework, and I am currently trying to add an array to my database when creating a new entry (row). The column in question is called "Keywords."  So here is my sql initialization code (which looks fine to me)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Email (
    Email_Id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Sender_Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Recipient_Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Body TEXT,
    Attachment_Path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Creation_Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    MaxKeywords INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Keywords VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Primary Key(Email_Id)
);
```

And here is the code in my add function that is crashing and burning:

```
public boolean add(final MessageDto emailDto){
    boolean result = false;
    int rowsAffected;
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    final String sql;

    sql = "INSERT INTO email (Sender_Email, Recipient_Email, Subject, Body, Attachment_Path, Creation_Date, MaxKeywords, Keywords) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try{
        rowsAffected = getJdbcTemplate().update(
                  new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                            PreparedStatement statement = 
                                    connection.prepareStatement(sql, new String[] {"emailId"});

                            String[] foo = {"A","B"};

                            statement.setString(1, emailDto.getFrom());
                            statement.setString(2, emailDto.getTo());
                            statement.setString(3, emailDto.getSubject());
                            statement.setString(4, emailDto.getBody());
                            statement.setString(5, emailDto.getAttachmentPath());
                            statement.setTimestamp(6, new Timestamp(emailDto.getCreationDate().getMillis()));
                            statement.setInt(7, emailDto.getMaxKeywordCount());
                            statement.setArray(8, connection.createArrayOf("varchar", foo));

                            return statement;
                        }
                      }, keyHolder);

        if(rowsAffected > 0){
            emailDto.setEmailId(keyHolder.getKey().intValue());
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The error thrown is:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; null; nested exception is java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
```

Help?

Comment: It says type isn't correct -- it wants a java.sql.Array

Comment: This link might help you.. [PreparedStatement Set Array](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/PreparedStatementSetArray.htm)

Comment: Not to be ungrateful @Smit, but Spring does not appear to know about oracle, so i cannot import it or use it... is this not a builtin part of java/spring?

Comment: which database are you using and what driver version? looks like the driver does not support setArray

Comment: @dorb, MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 -- and Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Why don't you just use `setString` and convert the String array to a single String?

Comment: @Jessermon - yes, the best idea i have had so far is to make it into a JSON string, and store that... but i feel some kind of moral "must work" feeling towards this setarray

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to abandon the `setArray` method, you can do this.  Use your own logic to convert the array into a string.  You are storing it in a `varchar` anyway, so you have to "flatten" the array.

```
    String[] foo = {"A","B"};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String bar : foo) {
        sb.append(bar);
        sb.append("\t");
    }
    statement.setArray(8, sb.toString());
```